# Scaling Kafka stream application across multiple users

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I have a setup where I'm pushing events to `kafka` and then running a [Kafka Streams](https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-kafka-streams-stream-processing-made-simple/) application on the same cluster. Is it fair to say that the only way to scale the `Kafka Streams` application is to scale the `kafka` cluster itself by adding nodes or increasing `Partitions`?

In that case, how do I ensure that my consumers will not bring down the cluster and ensure that the critical pipelines are always `"on"`. Is there any concept of `Topology Priority` which can avoid a possible downtime? I want to be able to expose the streams for anyone to build applications on without compromising the core pipelines. If the solution is to setup another kafka cluster, does it make more sense to use `Apache storm` instead, for all the adhoc queries? (I understand that a lot of consumers could still cause issues with the `kafka` cluster, but at least the `topology` processing is isolated now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not recommended to run your Streams application on the same servers as your brokers (even if this is technically possible). Kafka's Streams API offers an application-based approach -- not a cluster-based approach -- because it's a library and not a framework.

It is not required to scale your Kafka cluster to scale your Streams application. In general, the parallelism of a Streams application is limited by the number of partitions of your app's input topics. It is recommended to over-partition your topic (the overhead for this is rather small) to guard against scaling limitations.

Thus, it is even simpler to "offer anyone to build applications" as everyone owns their application. There is no need to submit apps to a cluster. They can be executed anywhere you like (thus, each team can deploy their Streams application the same way by which they deploy any other application they have). Thus, you have many deployment options from a WAR file, over YARN/Mesos, to containers (like Kubernetes). Whatever works best for you.

Even if frameworks like Flink, Storm, or Samza offer cluster management, you can only use such tools that are integrated with those frameworks (for example, Samza requires YARN -- no other options available). Let's say you have already a Mesos setup, you can reuse it for your Kafka Streams applications -- no need for a dedicated "Kafka Streams cluster" (because there is no such thing).

Comment: I read about overpartitioning and that streams is a library and not a framework. I get the first part but I'm still a little confused on how the kafka balances the processing in a topology. Ex. when I run the example given [here](https://gist.github.com/miguno/a9b44c1efc9b579565cfad75e543c808#file-wordcountlambdaexample-java) from my local machine, does the stream processing happen at my local machine or in the kafka cluster? And if I run the same topology over multiple machines, will kafka rebalance the load automatically?

Comment: It will execute on your local machine. That exactly the library part. If you have multiple machines, and you start the application multiple times, load will automatically balanced to both. (Kafka uses a so-called "group management protocol" to handle this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apache-kafka/5449/consumer-groups-and-offset-management/19387/what-is-a-consumer-group#t=201701251803271028858 and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+0.9+Consumer+Rewrite+Design and https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> An application’s processor topology is scaled by breaking it into
>   multiple tasks.
>
> More specifically, Kafka Streams creates a fixed number of tasks based
>   on the input stream partitions for the application, with each task
>   assigned a list of partitions from the input streams (i.e., Kafka
>   topics).
>
> The assignment of partitions to tasks never changes so that each task
>   is a fixed unit of parallelism of the application. Tasks can then
>   instantiate their own processor topology based on the assigned
>   partitions; they also maintain a buffer for each of its assigned
>   partitions and process messages one-at-a-time from these record
>   buffers.
>
> As a result stream tasks can be processed independently and in
>   parallel without manual intervention.
>
> It is important to understand that Kafka Streams is not a resource
>   manager, but a library that “runs” anywhere its stream processing
>   application runs. Multiple instances of the application are executed
>   either on the same machine, or spread across multiple machines and
>   tasks can be distributed automatically by the library to those running
>   application instances.
>
> The assignment of partitions to tasks never changes; if an application
>   instance fails, all its assigned tasks will be restarted on other
>   instances and continue to consume from the same stream partitions.

The processing of the stream happens in the machines where the application is running.

I recommend you to have a look to [this guide](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/architecture.html), it can help you to better understand the way Kafka Streams work.